# Create non existent association in database first entity framework model?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, foreign-keys

I have an entity model from a database that has not any FK and in my model i want to add one association between the columns that represent the association. Is there a way to make this with out having to create the FK on the DataBase? (i don't have any permission to create that FK on the DB).

Example:

```
TableA
- id (PK)
- idB
- someParam

TableB
- idB (PK)
- someParam2
- someParam3
```

Comment: I don't really understand your question, there is a relation between them but you can't map it? Can you provide more info about db model?

Comment: The idB column in TableA is just a int column and in my model i need to create the association with TableB

Answer (score 0):

Just manually define the FK in entity framework, without a real foreign key in your database I can imagine the queries will be very slow if your database is big.
The mapping can be something like this:

```
public class A
{
[Key]
[Required]
public int id {get; set;}

[ForeignKey("tableB")]
public int idB {get; set;}

public virtual TableB tableB {get; set;}
}
```

Or you can do it with fluent mapping (better in my opinion):

```
            modelBuilder.Entity<TableB>()
            .HasRequired(e => e.TableA)
            .WithOptional(e => e.TableB)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.idB);
```

This is just an example as I don't know the specific relation between tableA and tableB (one-to-optional, one-to-many...)

Another problem I can see with this approach is inserting/deleting/updating entities. Because there is no real foreign key present you will have to watch out not to insert duplicate records in tableB when calling `SaveChanges()`. 
A good article about it: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh708747.aspx